# Trouble with setting greeting note with JS on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I'm having trouble running a JS code from separate stylesheet on HTML page. Basically, I want to set an adequate greeting messages depending on the current hour of the day. I've searched and there are many ways to do it, but I am trying to get it work in this way and I didn't find a solution to this problem.

```js
window.onload = getGreeting();
    function getGreeting() {
    var time = new Date();
    var curHours = time.getHours();
    if (curHours < 10) {
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro jutro!";
    } if else (curHours < 20) {
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobar dan!";
    } if else {
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro vece!";
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="LakaRukaDent.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
<p id="greeting"></p>
</body>
```

When I run the HTML in Chrome the greeting doesn't appear. When I press f12 in Chrome it comes up with "*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <*", but I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I've checked syntax and functionality searching through the web but considering that I'm new with JS and HTML perhaps it could be some basic thing that I've skipped and I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the fix below. `window.onload` expects a function reference not returned value of a function, that is why i remove parenthesis over there. Also there was syntax error with `if else` statement.

```js
window.onload = getGreeting;
        function getGreeting() {
        var time = new Date();
        var curHours = time.getHours();
        if (curHours < 10) {
            document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro jutro!";
        } else if (curHours < 20) {
            document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobar dan!";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro vece!";
        }
    };
```

```html
<h1 id="greeting"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if` instead of `if else`.
Example from MDN:

```
if (x > 5) {

} else if (x > 50) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove the parentheses from `getGreeting` when assigning to `onload`, as `onload` accepts a function. Also, you have syntax errors with your if statements. It should be `else if` not `if else` like so:

```js
window.onload = getGreeting;
    function getGreeting() {
    var time = new Date();
    var curHours = time.getHours();
    if (curHours < 10) {
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro jutro!";
    } else if (curHours < 20) {
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro dan!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = "Dobro vece!";
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="greeting"></p>
```